# Build failing on .net Core app due to missing definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build my .NET Core app from the CLI using `dotnet build`, but every single time I get this error:

> 'IConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddEnvironmentVariables' and no extension method 'AddEnvironmentVariables' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfigurationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` where the problem is happening:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
             .AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
                 options.UseSqlServer(builder["Data:MyContext:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddOpenIddictCore<Application>(config => config.UseEntityFramework());

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddScoped<OpenIddictManager<ApplicationUser, Application>, CustomOpenIddictManager>();
    }
```

Looking at [this example](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.Server/Startup.cs) I see nothing obviously wrong with my `Startup.cs`.

**Update**
My `project.json` file:

```
{
  "compilationOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-alpha1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "OpenIddict.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict.EF": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ComponentModel": { "type": "build" }
      }
    },

    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0-rc2-*"
        }
      },

      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
      "imports": "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  },

  "content": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "config.json",
    "web.config"
  ],

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],

  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

**Oct 2018 Update:**
This problem does not occur when creating a new .NET Core 2.1 app in the latest build of VS 2017. Everything is now at a long-stable version since I asked this question.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You need the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/47b13050126fab7afa18e8636bb3c5d1f4022338/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesExtensions.cs) namespace in scope to get that extension method. Either fully qualify it, or add this to the top of your file:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

You also will need the NuGet reference [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables).

Comment: Thanks, it's building now. I thought the package was renamed or something, hence why I didn't see it. The core packages are always changing still.

Comment: @barnacle.m Remember the source code is on GitHub, so if you have questions about it you can always just go look at it.

Comment: Thanks @mason  It works, my issue was little bit different during upgrading my app to dotnetcore 3.1 from 2.2I encounter this issue. But after adding this nuget reference my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 76):

The correct package to add for .`AddEnvironmentVariables()` is `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables`

Answer (score 9):

I tried Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables but with no luck.  I already had Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration from NuGet.  I added [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets/)
 and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct for an AspNetCore applications, however for a Console app, for the following to work:

```
ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
```

You will need *all* of these Nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
```

Note that you only need this in your code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```