# Is ASP.NET Core RC2 Released?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Looking at the project.json file in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190082/build-failing-on-net-core-app-due-to-missing-definition) question and looking at other questions on SO about RC2 makes me think that RC2 has been released.  But I cannot find any official announcement that it has been released.  Does anyone know if it's been released?  If so, can you install it on top of RC1 or are there special installation procedures?

Comment: Not yet https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases

Comment: How about you down voters explain yourselves?  Did you even look at the link I provided?  Here's one of the dependencies from the project.json I referenced - "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-*".  It plainly says rc2.

Comment: And what about [these](https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples) sample projects with AspNetCore dependencies?

Comment: what does "Released" mean?  RC is a release ***candidate***, and on top of that RC1 is only tagged as a "Pre-Release" :O

Comment: @Kritner - Just like a beta version is released an RC version is released too.  What would you call it when they made the RC1 version available for download?  I would call that a release.

Comment: @ClintB yeah I saw, I wasn't trying to be snarky - depending on what your definition of release is, could change things around a little.  I was just trying to point out under the github page linked, that even RC1 is considered a "pre-release" (this could be considered both a release and non release - Schrodinger release if you will?).  Anyway - here's a little more information, but it doesn't seem like anything has been tagged on github as RC2 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/06/net-core-rc2-improvements-schedule-and-roadmap/

Comment: @ClintB There are RC2 "nightly builds" (apparently) I can't find a direct link to them, but here's a discussion on them: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1426  - I figured this was probably the case (hence my definition of release comment) - but am having a lot of trouble finding specifics. Edit: OHHH I think htis might be it: https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext - it's seemingly the nightly build NuGet repo for the yet to be release RC2.  I guess it's a release candidate candidate.

Comment: @Kritner - Ok, thanks for your time.  No hard feelings. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APS.Net Core RC2 will in all likelihood be released on or before 5/17/16 as Damian Edwards mentioned at the ASP.Net Community Stand-up on 5/10/16. As to the link you referenced, they are using nightly builds. You can actually get bits now from the nightly stream that are labeled "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc3-*" as the team has continued to finish polishing things up for release. These ports will end up being renamed to whatever management decides to call the final build. The Nuget server for Microsoft Nightly builds is https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v2/ You can add it to Visual Studio by going to Tools=>Options=>NuGet Package Manager=>Package Sources.[See NuGet Package Manager Image Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQiZq.png) However, being so close to a supported release version, it seems futile now. I assume Microsoft will support RC2 with a "Go-Live" license.

Comment: ASP.Net Community Stand-up features Damian Edwards, Scott Hanselman and Jon Galloway and can be seen at https://live.asp.net/ with new meetings every Tuesday.

Answer (score 2):

To be more specific.
ASP.Net Core RC2 will be released ither today (friday), or on tuseday next week.
From what I know, everything is done and set in escrow.
Only the tooling team is tracking a few bugs.

You will find full information here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9HqMZviaMg&list=PL0M0zPgJ3HSftTAAHttA3JQU4vOjXFquF&index=0

Answer (score 1):

RC2 will be released in mid-May.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ASP.NET Core installation guide](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows):

> Before you start
>
> Remove all previous versions of .NET Core from your system.

To do this use Add/Remove programs in Control Panel (Windows).

RC2 you can download from: [.NET Core Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#core)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has been released! You can find the various downloads at: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core